# Generate custom EF6 code first migration SQL after foreign key constraints

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm adding custom SQL to an EF6 code first migration. The SQL adds delete triggers to various tables. It's generating correct syntax and getting output as expected.

But the location of the output is giving me trouble. Code first migrations put all the foreign key constraints at the bottom of the generated SQL. When creating the constraints for a join table (used in a many-to-many association), the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause is added. All fine and dandy, except when I've added a delete trigger to one of the tables participating in that relationship -- cascade delete isn't allowed coming from a table with a delete trigger on it.

Ideally, I'd like to do one of two things -- either move my SQL to the bottom of the script (where I can yank the cascade deletes off the constraints after they're added) or somehow tell EF not to cascade delete certain particular join tables, while leaving the default behavior in place for the more common case where the cascade deletes are the correct thing to do.

Anyone have a clue as to how this can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to configure Cascade Delete using the fluent API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.cascadablenavigationpropertyconfiguration.willcascadeondelete(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.CascadableNavigationPropertyConfiguration.WillCascadeOnDelete%28System.Boolean%29

Comment: Yes, but cascade delete itself can be problematic if there are multiple delete paths, so in my case (and, in my experience, most cases where you have a moderately complex model) it doesn't work -- SqlServer doesn't even let it be set when it detects multiple paths. I'm using INSTEAD OF triggers to make it work: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/

Comment: I meant disable cascade delete!

Comment: Yes, that's possible (by removing the ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention), but note that I'll need to disable certain join tables only, and due to the fluent API's object model, you can't enable the cascade delete while defining the mapping for the join table. So it'll be either all or nothing. I'm hoping there's a mechanism that's more selective.